# Click event only during the push. Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to realize eye for showing the password. I needn`t a click. I need only when I pushing to the eye.

My code

HTML

```
<input [formControlName]="'password'" [type]="isShow ? 'text' : 'password'" class="input" />
<div class="icon-div">
   <mat-icon class="pointer-hover" (click)="toggleShow()" svgIcon="eye"></mat-icon>
</div>
```

TS

```
toggleShow(): void {
  this.isShow = !this.isShow;
}
```

Is there any event not a click, maybe somthing like "oNclicking"?

Comment: on mouse down is your choice. You should disable eye on mouse up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`mousedown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event) and [`mouseup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseup_event) events separately instead of the `click` event. In fact, `click` event is a combination of `mousedown` and `mouseup` events. From [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event):

> `click` fires after both the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events have
> fired, in that order.

```js
<mat-icon class="pointer-hover" (mousedown)="isShow=true" (mouseup)="isShow=false" svgIcon="eye"></mat-icon>
```

You also don't need the event handler since the flag `isShow` is toggled directly in the template.